# replace template with other when conditions are met

Tags: theming

I want to add a record do theme_hook_suggestions variable but only when specific conditions are met, especially when system is going to use a specific template in theme. In effect I want to replace one template with other.

I.e. - when user sees node with id = 50 and view mode == teaser and user has set some specific parameters system should use template node-special.tpl.php. In any other condition system should use base template node-50.tpl.php

I cannot do this, as far as I understand, in any *preprocess or *process functions basing on variables because there is no information available about what template are candidate for use.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT, more detailed explanation:

I'm trying to build a A/B testing system for e-commerce site I run. 
I want to set a A/B test where for selected base template a new variant will be defined and for chosen group of users this new variant will be used. I want to have a universal solution where I could configure this just by one line of code. It should work both for nodes, fields, blocks, pages templates. I just simply need to substitute one template field with another.

ie I want to have a universal config:

```
$ABconfig = array(
        'ABbigrelated' => array( //test name
                'basetemplate' => 'related-nodes', //base template
                'newtemplate' => 'related-nodes-bigimages', //new template
                'GAdimensions'  =>  'dimension2' //config for googleanalitics

        )
);
```

Comment: What makes you think you can't do it in a preprocess_node ? That's the first place I would try doing it.

Comment: @2pha I don't see how in any *process function get information about current  hook suggestions. If know how to get this information just give me a hint

Comment: ? you want to add your own suggestion? or use one of the standard ones? [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x) [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the list of template suggestions in your `preprocess` hook:

```
function drop_preprocess(&$variables) {
  $variant = drop_get_variant_for_current_user($variables);
  if ($variant) {
    $suggestions = array();
    foreach ($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] as $suggestion) {
      $suggestions[] = $suggestion
      $suggestions[] = $suggestion . '--' . $variant;
    }
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = $suggestions;
  }
}
```

This will add templates variants for all theme hook. So for instance, this allow you to override the `node.tpl.php` and `page.tpl.php` templates with `node--special.tpl.php` and `page--special.tpl.php` ones (when `drop_get_variant_for_current_user()` returns `'special'`. If the template for a variant does not exists, it will simply be ignored.

Note that the order of suggestions is preserved. If you have three specialized node templates: `node.tpl.php`, `node--special.tpl.php` and `node-article.tpl.php` (the default one, the 'special' variant and the template for article nodes), when rendering an `article` node, the 'node-article.tpl.php' will be used since `'node_article'` will be after both `'node'` and `'node__special'` in `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']`.

Because it will run for all templates used on the page, the use [a static cache](https://www.drupalwatchdog.com/volume-3/issue-2/drupal-static-caching) in `get_variant_for_current_user()` so the actual variant won't be computed again and again for the same request/template.

*Update:*

- The exact used template with be the last one in `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']` for which a template file exits. For instance if `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] == array('node', 'node--special', 'node-article', 'node-article--special')`, but only the `node.tpl.php`, `node-article.tpl.php` and `node--special.tpl.php` files exist, then `node--special.tpl.php` will be used.
- The `drop_get_variant_template()` function is the one where you put your variant selection logic (and that has to be written).

Comment: Thanks, for answer it essencially address what I described. But I wasn't fully clear in my question.

Comment: I'm looking for something more general or universal. I'm trying to build a A/B testing system for e-commerce site I run. I want to set a A/B test where for selected base template a new variant will be defined and for chosen group of users this new variant will be used. I want to have a universal solution where I could configure this just by one line of code. It should work both for nodes, fields, blocks, pages templates. I just simply need to substitute one template field with another.

Comment: I updated the answer with what should be a suitable solution to alter the suggestions for all templates.

Comment: thanks for the update but it didn't address main issue - how to know which onexactly template file will be used. Those drop_get_variant_template is an existing function?

Comment: The exact used template with be the last one in `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']` for which a template file exits. The `drop_get_variant_template()` function is supposed to be the one where you put your variant selection logic.